# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken and domain names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've discovered that using a domain such as *foo.bar.uk.com* causes `Rails` to throw an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` when submitting any forms.

*foo.bar.co.uk* and *foo.bar.co.com* work, but for some reason *foo.bar.uk.com* throws the error.

Is there a list of acceptable domain/TLDs somewhere?

It also throws the error on *foo.bar.eu.com*

**Update:**

removing:

```
:domain => :all
```

from:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_session', :domain => :all
```

allows the form to submit, but it doesn't fix login (i.e. other cookie related functionality).

Comment: i don't see any problem using those domains. tried it out here: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/commits/subdomains what kind of error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you are doing exactly? Your site is one server, and reachable through three domain names? A cookie is domain specific afaik, so your session/cookies are only valid for one domain. You are not cross-posting I presume? The `InvalidAuthenticityToken` is stored in the form and the session. So somehow you start with a new session. A session is stored in the cookie and domain-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Rails gets confused when your project is deployed in a domain that contains more than one TLD. In Rails 3, if that's what you're using, ,you have to change the file config/initializers/session_store.rb.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  key: 'YOUR KEY, THIS VALUE IS ALREADY DEFINED',
  domain: '.co.uk'
}
```

Hope it helps